# Why video is not playing on Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, gstreamer

Why my video isn't playing in VideoView on Android emulator? Input video is encoded in h.264 codec, baseline profile (320x240), by x264enc (from GStreamer) and is in mp4 format, muxed by mp4mux. My question is what to do and which requirements I need to meet, to play this existing video file.

Comment: Do not use emulator for playing videos. Its not supportet and limited. Use you own device for this

Comment: Thank you! Works on actual device.